# Using regex on python + beautiful soup

Tags: python, parsing

I have an html page like this:

```
<td class="subject windowbg2">
 <div>
  <span id="msg_152617">
   <a href= SOME INFO THAT I WANT </a>
  </span>
 </div>
 <div>
  <span id="msg_465412">
   <a href= SOME INFO THAT I WANT</a>
  </span>
 </div>
```

as you can see the id="msg_465412" have a variable number, so this is my code:

```
import urllib.request, http.cookiejar,re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

contenturl = "http://megahd.me/peliculas-microhd/"
htmll=urllib.request.urlopen(contenturl).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmll)

print (soup.find('span', attrs=re.compile(r"{'id': 'msg_\d{6}'}")))
```

in the last line I tried to find all the "span" tags that contain an id that can be msg_###### (with any number) but something is wrong in my code and it doesn't find anything.

P.S: all the code I want is in a table with 6 columns and I want the third column of all rows, but I thought that it was easier to use regex

Comment: Shouldn't that `regex` be `r"{'id': 'msg_\d{6}'}"`

Comment: yeah, I modified it in the before posting and didn't notice, but still can't find anything in the html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're a bit mixed up with your `attrs` argument ... at the moment it's a regex which contains the string representation of a dictionary, when it needs to be a dictionary containing the attribute you're searching for and a regex for its value.

This ought to work:

```
print (soup.find('span', attrs={'id': re.compile(r"msg_\d{6}")}))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following:

```
soup.find_all("span" id=re.compile("msg_\d{6}"))
```